# IDLE highlighted text loses syntax highlighting

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, python-idle

In the newest version of python IDLE will remove syntax highlighting on text selected. How do I fix or remove this? Is there anything in the tkinter code that I have to change?

## Specs (only the Python version changed):

OS - Macos

Python version - 3.10.4 (Worked fine in 3.9)

Tk/tcl versions - 8.6

## Images:

### Not from idlelib:

[image: Not]

### Image from IDLE:

[image: IDLE]

Comment: While text is selected, the selection highlighting overrides the syntax highlighting.  When unselected, the syntax highlighting reappears, as least for me on Win 10, 3.9 and 3.11.  This is by design and AFAIK, has always been the case.  If syntax colors do not return, add exact detail of system, python, and tk versions, along with text and exact details of your actions.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy For Mac it used to stay highlighted even when selected. Also, when I create a tag on other text (not highlighted by idlelib) it doesn't lose the highlighting and it is a recent change

Comment: I reloaded the latest 3.9.13 with the python.org macOS Universal 2 installer, which installs tk 8.6.12, and it behaves as shown in the image.  I consider this proper behavior.  It is the way stackoverflow behaves when one selects highlighted code, or the end of a comment with black and blue text.  If there was a change, it may have been a side-effect of fixing a bug.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Which photo? What does stackoverflow behaviour have to do with this. I am quite confused right now

Comment: The "Image from IDLE", where the selection tag overlays to syntax tag.  I should have said, 'The way that Firefox and Edge display SO'.  The point? Selection marking is not standardized, and IDLE is constrained to what tk can do. ... This issue was duplicated at https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/93266 and I will make further responses there.